# Imprecise google map by longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im trying to save longitude and latitude on google map, but it seems to be imprecise (fails some meters). Given this:

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), { zoom: 19, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(event) {
    this.position.lat()
    this.position.lng()
  });
```

if I save these coordinages and copy-paste them here: http://www.gps-coordinates.net/ it wont return the exactly same position.

Comment: sometimes it fails some meters, sometimes its precise

Comment: I've found google maps isn't always dead accurate - I've seen it vary by hundreds of metres